# Creating Loop Cuts in any direction

Tags: loop

I want to create loop cuts in a direction that Blender does not allow me to. As far as I know.
Anyone have a solution how to create the loop cuts as shown in the image attached.[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the knife or knife project tool?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use *Knife Project* for this task. *Please be aware that this approach doesn't give you a clean topology.*

You will need to add another object that is used to add the cuts. In your case I would use a *Circle* (*Add > Circle* in object mode). Select the *Circle* first and then the object you would like to apply the knife project on. Position your viewport perspective so that the *Circle* is placed where you'd want the cuts in the target mesh to be. Switch to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), open the operator search (<kbd>F3</kbd> or *Edit > Operator Search*), find the *Knife Project* operator and execute it.

[image: The two objects]

[image: Knife project]

[image: The result]

Comment: .. and you can project a lattice, or concentric loops, etc, etc, by using a suitable object, with its faces deleted, as a cutter.